issue with DNS server communication in ubuntu+docker
I am trying to setup a local DNS server in ubuntu using this tutorial.
https://blog.yarsalabs.com/bind9-dns-server-setup-in-docker/

this is my docker run command:
docker run -d -p 1153:53/tcp -p 1153:53/udp -p 127.0.0.1:953:953/tcp --rm --name=dns-master --net=labnet --ip=192.168.0.2 

However, when I try to query the DNS server, it says communication error.


Dockerfile
#Base Bind9 Image

FROM internetsystemsconsortium/bind9:9.18

RUN apt update \
  && apt install -y \
  bind9-doc \
  bind9-dnsutils \
  bind9-host \
  libedit2 \
  dnsutils \
  geoip-bin \
  mariadb-server \
  net-tools

# Copy configuration files
COPY configuration/named.conf.options /etc/bind/
COPY configuration/named.conf.local /etc/bind/
COPY configuration/db.vishnu /etc/bind/zones/

# Expose Ports
EXPOSE 53/tcp
EXPOSE 53/udp
EXPOSE 953/tcp

# Start the Name Service
CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-g", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf", "-u", "bind"]

zone file:
db.vishnu
$TTL    1d ; default expiration time (in seconds) of all RRs without their own TTL value
@       IN      SOA     ns1.vishnu. root.vishnu. (
                  3      ; Serial
                  1d     ; Refresh
                  1h     ; Retry
                  1w     ; Expire
                  1h )   ; Negative Cache TTL

; name servers - NS records
     IN      NS      ns1.vishnu.

; name servers - A records
ns1.vishnu.             IN      A      192.168.0.1
one.vishnu.             IN      A      192.168.1.1
two.vishnu.             IN      A      192.168.1.2

named.conf.local
zone "vishnu" {    
    type master;    
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.vishnu";

not sure, where am I missing. pointers please.

Have you created the network? docker network create --name lab-net --subnet 192.168.0.0/16

$ docker network inspect labnet 
[
    {
        "Name": "labnet",
        "Id": "049943c94ec4cbd3dd0c5dfcfbe58abfc47f924324653dc3cefd144b432668a6",
        "Created": "2024-06-16T22:59:00.141860014+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1"
                }


update:
I deleted the network I have created, and create another network without specifying the ip range. It worked.
